# A problem on finite normal extension .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Question number $11.$

[image]

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ Actually, we know $L$ being a finite normal extension, is a splitting field of some polynomial $p(x)$ over $k.$

A hint is given :

Show that $\text{deg}    g(x)=\text{deg} h(x).$

But, I am unable to show the above assertion also .

And, how to show that the $k-algebra$ automorphism $\sigma$ of $L$ maps $g(x)$ to $h(x) ?$

A hint is warmly appreciated .Thanks in advance .

Comment: Take roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $g$ and $h$ (in some field extension) and show that there is a homomorphism over $k$ sending $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Show that such a homomorphism restricts to an $k$-automorphism of $L$ with the desired property

Comment: dear leoli, if you please write a short answer on how to construct the homomorphism , it will be very helpful for me ...actually , our course is going very fast (online mode) and I am not parallel with it .

Comment: Take a splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $L$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be roots of $g$ and $h$ respectively. As $f$ is irreducible over $k$ there is a $k$-isomorphism $k(\alpha)\to k(\beta)$. This can be extended to an automorphism $\tilde{\sigma}$ of $E$. Let $\sigma=\tilde{\sigma}\rvert_L$ be the restriction of $\tilde{\sigma}$ to $L$. Note that $\sigma(L)=L$ (why?), so this is an automorphism of $L$. Now look at what $\sigma,\tilde{\sigma}$ do to $g(\alpha)$.